# How to disable copying from google sheets for a user who must be able to edit the document?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a situation where I need to block copy or select mode in a Google Sheets for a user who should be able to edit it or even paste data in it. The OS is Windows. There is not any range limitations, it should be all cells in the spreadsheet. It's OK if the user selects/copies just one cell at a time.
I am not looking for a 100% solution, as I am sure it is either not possible or should be too complicated. It can be via Google Apps Script or maybe browser settings change (like adding some JavaScript code to prohibit copy or selection in all tabs of the browser). 
I am OK if the user can theoretically remove that restriction, because I am sure the user will hardly understand such kind of things. Even if he try to do that, I can figure that out eventually.
So, what I am looking for is to make it harder copying from a Google Sheets.

Comment: Your best bet would be to try permutation and combination around "Protecting the sheet and assign user specific access"

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible.  You probably should include the google-spreadsheet tag.

Comment: Thanks, I added tags.